# react-redux how to render response data from api

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-redux-form

I followed one of the tutorial from youtube. When I do that it works completely fine. But when I try different api, I'm getting an error items are not defined. Can someone please help me to understand what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

//actions

```
import axios from 'axios' 
export function fetchTweets(brandUrl, responseCode){
let url = brandUrl + '/api/offer/' + responseCode;
return function(dispatch){
axios.get(url)
  .then((response) => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'FETCH_TWEETS_FULFILLED',
      payload: response.data
    })
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'FETCH_TWEETS_REJECTED',
      payload: error
    })
  })
}
}
```

//reducer

```
export default function reducer(state = {
tweets: [],
fetching: false,
fetched: false,
error: null
}, action) {
switch(action.type){
case 'FETCH_TWEETS_PENDING' :{
  return { ...state, fetching: true }
}
case 'FETCH_TWEETS_REJECTED' : {
  return { ...state, fetching: false, error: action.payload }
}
case 'FETCH_TWEETS_FULFILLED' : {
  return { ...state, 
    fetching: false, 
    fetched: true, 
    tweets: action.payload }
}
}
return state
}
```

//main component

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchTweets } from '../actions/tweetsActions'
class Layout extends React.Component{
fetchTweets(){
this.props.dispatch(fetchTweets(brandUrl, responseCode))
}
render(){
const { tweets } = this.props;
if(!tweets.length){
  return <button value="Load" onClick={this.fetchTweets.bind(this)}>Load </button>
}  
console.log(tweets.response.mainItems.length)
return (
  <div>
    <p>{tweets.statusMessage}</p>
    <ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
);
}
}
function mapStateToProp(state){
return {
  tweets : state.tweets.tweets
}
}
export default connect(mapStateToProp)(Layout)
```

//store

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import promise from 'redux-promise-middleware'
import logger from 'redux-logger'
import reducer from './reducers'
const middleware = applyMiddleware(promise(), thunk, logger())
export default createStore(reducer, middleware)
```

// API Response
[image]

Comment: Did you try debugging step by step? 1. Check the data in your action `payload`. 2. Check the data of your store after the reducer has handled the action. 3. Check the the value of the prop in your component. 

Seems like you have some discrepancies in the main component. You are calling `tweets.response.mainItems`, for the tweets, yet you call `tweets.statusMessage` for the status message. This seems a bit off. Perhaps you should call just `tweets.mainItems` instead?

Comment: Hi @VanDanic I did debug and everything looks fine. It does print statusMessage. StatusMessage and response are on same level and mainItems is the children of response. When I select any child property from response, it throws an error. 

[Debug Image Link](http://imgur.com/z0Flmfb)

Answer (score 0):

1. in main component's mapStateToProps function ,why you are accessing tweets by assigning state.tweets.tweets ,though you dont have reducer named tweets ,and you are not using combineReducer function (which one use in case of multiple reducer).
2. So you can easily access tweets by writing this.state.tweets .and you can print state in mapStateToProps before returning which might be helpful for debugging......

```js
//main component
function mapStateToProp(state){
console.log(state,"=====>")
return {
  tweets : state.tweets
}
```